# Pentaho Adhoc reports - allow limited data access to user

Tags: pentaho

I have created a set of metadata objects and exposed it to a set of users to create adhoc reports. The user can use the meta data objects and create their own reports.

However, the problem is - the objects correspond to tables having millions of records for last 5 years. I want that the business user should be able to access data only for last 6 months, so that their reports do not get flooded with excessive data. At the same time, my database & application server need not suffer due to excessive load.

How can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can do this with row level security, but you'll have to read up on it:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc1x/06.+Adding+Row+Level+Security+to+a+Pentaho+Metadata+Model

You should be able to put a clause on that restricts the date field to be within 6 months. The 6 months code needs to be a libformula code I believe.

Latest versions have proper limit functionality which may help. But that is with PIR, are you using that? If not then see whether Saiku Adhoc supports this functionality..